# Usage of to and for

Tags: grammaticality, lyrics

I was wondering why the singer first sings *a little bit of my life **for** you,* and after, *a little bit of your time **to** me*. Is there any difference in how these prepositions are used? Is this unique to this song lyric, or would the difference extend into everyday conversation, or formal writing?

> *I'll give a little bit
>
>   I'll give a little bit of my life for you
>
>   So give a little bit
>
>   Give a little bit of your time to me
>
>   See the man with the lonely eyes
>
>   Take his hand, you'll be surprised*

Comment: I think the writer could have switched the prepositions, and the song meaning would be essentially the same. There might be a slight variation in the nuance, but both words mean that you are devoting some of your time (or some of your life) toward the other person. It's not like one of the words is correct, and the other would be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just an almost imperceptible shift of emphasis. In the first instance, the lyricist is saying...

> 1: *I've given [up] something **for** you [for your benefit]...*

...where in the second instance it's more a case of asking for something in return...

> 2: ...so you should give something **to** me.

In both cases, the "underlying" emphasis is on the situation from the *speakers's* point of view (in #1 he *does something **for** someone else*, in #2 he wants them to *give something **to** him* in return).

As J.R. comments, the difference is negligible, and the two prepositions could feasibly even be reversed.

---

Note that in general you *give [something] **to*** someone. But in this particular case the meaning is closer to ***give up*** (sacrifice, go without). This can be seen as a "self-contained action" rather than the giving of a "thing, object". In such contexts, ***for*** is used to specify who benefits from the action.

> *My wife is asthmatic, so I gave up smoking **for** her [optionally: sake, benefit, comfort, health, etc.]*.
>    **NOT**
>   *✲My wife is asthmatic, so I gave up smoking **to** her*. (where ✲ marks a usage as unacceptable).